# Listening for async messsages in a Kafka Connect SourceTask

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

My 3rd-party app emits async messages i.e. "Matter creation successful", "Workflow 124-C completion failed", etc on a particular port.  Currently I capture these messages with a standard ServerSocket/ClientListener paradigm.

But now I'd like to create a Kafka Source Connector that listens for these messages and stores them in a queue then at certain intervals converts them to SourceRecords and sends them on their way to our Kafka cluster. I'm trying to use the Connect API , extending SourceTask and overriding its methods with pieces from my paradigm.

```
public class MySourceTask extends SourceTask {
    Queue q_msg;
    ServerSocket ss;
    
    long last_execution;
    static final long Interval = 10000L;

    @Override
    public void start(Map<String,String> props) {
        this.q_msg = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String>();
        this.last_execution = System.currentTimeMillis();
        this.ss = new ServerSocket(19092);
        this.istream = new InputStream();
    }

    @Override
    public List<SourceRecord> poll() throws InterruptedException {
        List<SourceRecord> llist = new ArrayList<SourceRecord>();
        if( System.currentTimeMillis() > this.last_execution + Interval) {
            this.last_execution = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while(( String msg = q_msg.poll()) != null) {
                llist.add( new SourceRecord( sourcePartition, sourceOffset, "app.msg", msg));
            }
        return llist; // might be empty
    }

}
```

but I'm clearly missing some stuff. Or maybe I don't need some thing due to Kafka "magic"

Comment: Unclear what you think you're missing. But, I'd suggest looking into Apache Camel's Kafka Connect Support. I believe it offers a way to open a generic TCP input server.

Answer (score 0):

### Developing a Simple Source Connector

- Developing a connector only requires implementing two interfaces, **the Connector** and **Task**.
- Creating a class that inherits from **SourceConnector** and add a couple of fields that will store parsed configuration information (the source of the data stream in your case it is that 3rd party System and the topic to send data to).
- The easiest method to fill in is **taskClass()**, which defines the class that should be instantiated in worker processes to actually read the data.

  ```
    public class FileStreamSourceConnector extends SourceConnector {
        private String filename;
        private String topic;
    @Override
    public Class<? extends Task> taskClass() {
        return FileStreamSourceTask.class;
    }
  ```
- Add some standard lifecycle methods, start() and stop()

  ```
     public void start(Map<String, String> props) {
            // The complete version includes error handling as well.
            filename = props.get(FILE_CONFIG);
            topic = props.get(TOPIC_CONFIG); }
              public void stop() {
            // Nothing to do since no background monitoring is required.
  ```

  }
- The real core of the implementation is in taskConfigs().

> ```
>     @Override
>     public List<Map<String, String>> taskConfigs(int maxTasks) 
> {
>         ArrayList<Map<String, String>> configs = new ArrayList<>();
>         // Only one input stream makes sense.
>         Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<>();
>         if (filename != null)
>             config.put(FILE_CONFIG, filename);
>         config.put(TOPIC_CONFIG, topic);
>         configs.add(config);
>         return configs;
>     }
> ```

SourceTask provides two APIs to commit offsets in the source system which has an acknowledgment mechanism for messages: **commit** and **commitRecord**.

Overriding these methods allows the source connector to acknowledge messages in the source system, either in bulk or individually, once they have been written to Kafka.

- Just as with the connector, we need to create a class inheriting from the appropriate base Task class. It also has some standard lifecycle methods.

> public class FileStreamSourceTask extends SourceTask
>
> ```
> {
>     String filename;
>     InputStream stream;
>     String topic;
>  
>     @Override
>     public void start(Map<String, String> props) {
>         filename = props.get(FileStreamSourceConnector.FILE_CONFIG);
>         stream = openOrThrowError(filename);
>         topic = props.get(FileStreamSourceConnector.TOPIC_CONFIG);
>     }
>     @Override
>     public synchronized void stop() {
>         stream.close();
>     }
> ```

The method **stop()** is synchronized. This will be necessary because SourceTasks are given a dedicated thread which they can block indefinitely, so they need to be stopped with a call from a different thread in the Worker.

- Next, we implement the main functionality of the task, the poll() method which gets events from the input system and returns a List.

> @Override public List poll() throws
> InterruptedException
>
> ```
> {
>         try 
> {
>             ArrayList<SourceRecord> records = new ArrayList<>();
>             while (streamValid(stream) && records.isEmpty()) 
> {
>                 LineAndOffset line = readToNextLine(stream);
>                 if (line != null) {
>                     Map<String, Object> sourcePartition = Collections.singletonMap("filename", filename);
>                     Map<String, Object> sourceOffset = Collections.singletonMap("position", streamOffset);
>                     records.add(new SourceRecord(sourcePartition, sourceOffset, topic, Schema.STRING_SCHEMA, line));
>                 } else {
>                     Thread.sleep(1);
>                 }
>             }
>             return records;} catch (IOException e) 
> {
>             // Underlying stream was killed, probably as a result of calling stop. Allow to return
>             // null, and driving thread will handle any shutdown if necessary.
>         }
> return null;  
> }
> ```

The method **poll()** is going to be called repeatedly, and for each call it will loop trying to read records from the file.

For each record it reads, it also tracks the file offset. It uses this information to create an output SourceRecord with four pieces of information: the **source partition**, **source offset** (byte offset in the source record), **output topic name**, and **output value** (the data record, and we include a schema indicating this value will always be a string).